# Oracle SQL dynamic date insert

Tags: sql, oracle, date, dynamic

I have a table with FX rates which has some missing data. I have a from_ccy_code, to_ccy_code, fx_date and fx_rate columns. What I'm looking to do is where from_ccy_code = USD and to_ccy_code = EUR, if record doesn't exist for that date, then insert a record (fx_rate set to 1).
In this case, all other values are static except the date that the fx_rate is to be inserted for. I can write SQL to insert for a specific date if the value doesn't exist but I need the date to be dynamic in my inserts. Could someone please help with how this can be done?

The below is what I have so far. I know this may not be the correct syntax but once correct this should work for a set-date. I don't know how I could make the date dynamic in a scenario like this.

```
insert into fx_rates (from_ccy_code, to_ccy_code, fx_date, fx_rate) 
select 'USD', 'EUR'
from dual
where not exists(select * 
                 from fx_rates
                 where (from_ccy_code ='USD' and to_ccy_code ='EUR' and fx_date = '01-OCT-14'));
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean you want to insert a record for all missing dates from a range of dates, in a single statement? Or just that you want to make your fixed date a parameter?

Comment: I want to insert a record for all the missing dates from a pre-defined date range. I'd like to do this ideally in a single statement if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate all the dates for a range with a `connect by` clause; for example to see all days from October 1st to yesterday:

```
select date '2014-10-01' + level - 1
from dual
connect by level <= trunc(sysdate) - date '2014-10-01';

DATE'2014-10-01'+LEVEL-1
------------------------
01-OCT-14                
02-OCT-14                
...
26-OCT-14                
27-OCT-14                

 27 rows selected
```

You can use your own date range of course, I'm just using fixed values to demonstrate - you'd maybe really want bind values for the start and end date, or from the start of the current month - using `trunc(sysdate, 'MM')` instead of the fixed start date. Depends how and when this will be run I suppose.

You can add fixed values to the same query, use it as a common table expression (or in-line view), and use a similar `not exists` construct to check for values which you would need to insert:

```
with t (from_ccy_code, to_ccy_code, fx_date, fx_rate) as (
  select 'USD', 'EUR', date '2014-10-01' + level - 1, 1
  from dual
  connect by level <= trunc(sysdate) - date '2014-10-01'
)
select * from t
where not exists(
  select * 
  from fx_rates fr
  where fr.from_ccy_code = t.from_ccy_code
  and fr.to_ccy_code = t.to_ccy_code
  and fr.fx_date = t.fx_date
);
```

And you can base an `insert` on that, but it might be cleaner to adapt it to a `merge` statement:

```
merge into fx_rates fr
using (
  select 'USD' as from_ccy_code, 'EUR' as to_ccy_code,
    date '2014-10-01' + level - 1 as fx_date, 1 as fx_rate
  from dual
  connect by level <= trunc(sysdate) - date '2014-10-01'
) t
on (
  t.from_ccy_code = fr.from_ccy_code
  and t.to_ccy_code = fr.to_ccy_code
  and t.fx_date = fr.fx_date
)
when not matched then
  insert (from_ccy_code, to_ccy_code, fx_date, fx_rate)
  values (t.from_ccy_code, t.to_ccy_code, t.fx_date, t.fx_rate);
```

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6a238/1).